# Importing UK Land Registry data into Quantum GIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, united-kingdom

We have purchased data from the UK Land Registry to import into Quantum GIS however when I do so using the Coordinate referencing systems of OSGB 36/ British National Grid (EPSG:27700) the data appears to be stretched compared to our existing paper OS maps.

I assume that I have a setting somewhere which is incorrect but being new to GIS and Quantum GIS I do not know where to look. Can anyone help?

Comment: try adding the wms version and see if it matches your shapefile.  http://inspire.landregistry.gov.uk/inspire/ows?Service=WMS&Request=Getcapabilities

Comment: What data format are you working with?

Comment: what is the projection of your project?

Answer (score 1):

I found out my mistake (I did say I was new to GIS!) Although I was setting the CRS for the layer I was importing I had not set OSGB 36/British National Grid as the project CRS in project propeties, it was set to WGS 84.